# How to pass array as an argument in onclick function using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

In one method I defined the HTML in that one onclick function is there. When user clicks that link it passes the array as an argument

```
html += '<div class="" ><a onclick=showComments(comment)>View Comments</a>'

html += '<div class="" ><a onclick=showComments(\"comment\")>View Comments</a>'
```

In the above code how to call the show-comments() method. I tried all the possibilities. Can someone help me, please. I spent 3 hours on this.

How to pass array object as an argument in javascript.is it possible to pass paramenters

Comment: Where is your array? If array variable is assigned then you can pass that array variable as a parameter

Comment: Is showComments defined anywhere else as global function ? What you mean by passing of array object bcoz in question you are passing string. Please answer these 2 things.

Comment: In this code comment declared as an array

Comment: comment:[{ }] basically comments look like this